# Nagios place child service under parent

Tags: nagios

I'm looking for a way to structure **services** been monitored so that I can set a *parent* service above the *child* services and that only notifications are triggered if the parent experiences an outage rather than alerts for all the children.

Can you recommend an approach that I should take to implement this and maybe some example configuration?

Answer (score 2):

What you want are [Service Dependencies](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/dependencies.html).

If you're configuring many of these, you might want to use [Service Groups](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objectdefinitions.html#servicegroup) to make your life easier. See the [Time-Saving Tricks For Object Definitions](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/objecttricks.html) page for examples.

Comment: What I have done is created a service dependency. The issue I am having is that when the child service experiences an outage alerts are NOT sent out. The Nofification failure criteria that I have configured is o, w, u, c. Why are notifications not been sent out when the parent is alive but the child is down?

Comment: It's behaving exactly as you have it configured. 'o' is for "OK", which means you are suppressing child alerts when the parent is OK (also when it's (w)arning, (u)nknown, and (c)ritical). See the Object Definitions docs for what the different option letters mean.